# UIButton - setTitle vs setAttributedTitle - button not resized with later

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am dynamically setting text for UIButton.
If I use `setTitle("\u{25CF} Hello world", for: .normal)`, button is resized and I can see the whole text ("● Hello world")

However, when I use `setAttributedTitle`, button is not resized and the text is shorted with dots (like "● He...ld")

```
let desc = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{25CF}", attributes: [NNSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize * 0.4, weight: .light)])
desc.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Hello world"))
self.setAttributedTitle(desc, for: .normal)
```

My button is set programatically via

```
button = UIButton()
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
button.contentEdgeInsets =  UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Button is added to `UIStackView` via `addArrangedSubview`. There are no constraints attached to the button.

Before title is set, I call `layoutIfNeeded()` on parent view.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to specify font size for appended attributed text

```
let desc = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{25CF}", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize * 0.4, weight: .light)])
desc.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Hello world"), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)]))
self.setAttributedTitle(desc, for: .normal)
```

Comment: NNSAttributedString in first line has an extra 'N'....otherwise, works fine!